# Need to send email notification on visual studio run

Tags: visual-studio, notifications, automated-tests, execution

I'm executing a test-execution project using visual studio 2005 (using the pnunit framework and C# but its not relevant). The total execution time is more than 40 hours. In between if there are any environment problems on the network (external factors like remote server is down, db is down etc) the code stops executing. This creates a problem because when I notice the error I'll have to manually set external factors right and again resume the run. So it becomes important to keep checking the execution progress frequently to make sure we are not losing time due to halted execution, which is troublesome.

I looking for a way to somehow either triggering an email/batch script/exe/anything when the code stops running. Is there any way I could achieve this? Any ideas?

Thanks,
Mugen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to trigger an email at the end of the application, then I would suggest putting the code [here](http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/29291) at the end of your execution.

Comment: What a great big fool I am! Something so simple and what was I thinking? I've decided to get rid of the email idea and will use way2sms api to send sms now. Thanks a load for your help.